# Why is the last element in my flex column not aligned?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

Here is how it looks like: https://gyazo.com/77de215669cf2d9cd3ca35a0e064c7bf

I'm not sure why the last box isn't in the center. This is my css code:

```
 .recipe1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
}

.recipe2{
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px rgb(71,71,71);
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background: white;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div className="recipe1">
        <div className="recipe2">
            <h1 className="display-4 p-3">{title}</h1>
            <ul> {/*Ingredients is an array of objects, so need to iterate through it with map to display*/}
                {ingredients.map(ingredient => (
                    <li className="lead">{ingredient.text}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            <p>Calories: {Math.floor(calories)}g</p>
            <img className={style.image} src={image} alt="Cannot display :("></img>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm using react and bootstrap so there's some other stuff in there that looks different.

Comment: Your divs arent balanced. where is recipe1?

Comment: can please post the entire code (html + css) you have mor div closign tags then opening tags. making it hard to reproduce the error if you only got parts of the code and then more closing then opening tags.

Comment: Sorry, seems like I ommited the first tag

Comment: Get your attention to the 3rd line from bottom (HTML) you have there a tag `</img>`. Delete that tag, it does not exist. `<img>` does not need a closing tag. Might messing up the other tags afetrwards.

Comment: Do you have it hosted somewhere so we can check it... I can't figure anything from the code snippet :(

Comment: @tacoshy I tried but it did not change, thanks anyway

Comment: @AhmadDalao Thanks for trying, I will deploy it tomorrow and link it here if anyone would like to see, sorry what I posted is unclear.

Comment: Wtf actually I just fixed it, I changed justify-content to ```center``` as opposed to ```space-around``` in recipe1. Thanks guys :)